# Sum of a rate constant gives the total decay rate

Tags: kinetics

I want to ask a question about the sum of a rate constant to yield the total decay rate.

From previous studies, the rate of a reaction can be expressed evidently as

$$\ce{v_{rate} = k[A]}$$

where $\ce{A}$ is a molecule in a reaction.

I studied today about unimolecular photochemistry and that a molecule in its excited state $\ce{S_1}$ can do a number of processes:

- Fluoresence (emit a photon and return to its ground state), $\ce{F}$
- Intersystem crossing (convert to a triplet state and then relax), $\ce{ISC}$
- Internal conversion (release heat to the environment and relax back to the ground state), IC
- Photochemistry (be involved in a reaction), PC

and according to the lecture material, the *total decay rate* can be expressed as:

$$\ce{k_F + k_{ISC} + k_{IC} + K_{PC}}$$

i.e. the sum of the rate constants.

But I thought that from my studies, the *total decay **rate*** is expressed as:

$$\ce{v_{total \ decay \ rate} = (k_F + k_{ISC} + k_{IC} + K_{PC})[A]}$$

so why do I not include the concentration term as part of the total decay rate?

My thought was that $\frac{v_{\ total \ decay \ rate}}{[A]}$ is expressed as the *total decay rate* and hence it can be expressed as the sum of the rate constants, but I want to check that my logic is correct.

Why is the total decay rate expressed as a sum of all the rate constants of the expressions above?

Comment: Because it's not exactly a first rate reaction. More like pseudo-zeroth order, depending on illumination.

Comment: @Mithoron can you explain this a bit further - I'm a bit confused here apologies!

Comment: It looks to me like an example of the common misuse of "rate" when they mean "rate constant".

Comment: In your usage v is rate (conc /time) and k is rate constant in your case 1/time and as @Andrew writes you are confusing them. And yes rate constants do add  as all process start from the same excited state. As you write $k=k_F+k_{isc}$ etc

Answer (score 1):

I am simply confusing two different variables here, *rate* and *rate constants*.

In this situation, the sum of the rate constants is the sum of the individual rate constants of the processes occuring in the reaction i.e.

$$\ce{k_F + k_{ISC} + k_{IC} + K_{PC}}$$

This is consistent with my current knowledge.

It should be referred to as "total decay rate constant"

Of course, the rate equation can still be written here as:

$$\ce{v_{rate} = k[A]}$$